# What is the size of this microcontroller? Having trouble reading a data sheet

Tags: microcontroller, components, datasheet

I am trying to find a small enough microcontroller for a project, but I am not familiar with the notation used to denote the sizes in this image:
[image] What does that mean when it says 12,20/11,80 SQ and 7,50 TYP.  The image is from [this datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430f249.pdf).  OR is this not where I find the physical dimensions? If these do not denote the physical dimensions of the part, then where in the datasheet is that written?

Comment: SQ (I think) meaning that the part is square, and that's why only one dimension is shown. Other than that, the number under the line is the minimum, above the line is the maximum.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Am I correct about "SQ"?

Comment: It's 12x12 (mm of course). Tolerance of 0.2mm.

Comment: By the way, smallest come in smaller  packages: BGA or QFN or such.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum WLCSP - wafer level chip scale package.

Comment: That would be too exotic, even for me.

Comment: It is just a hair under half an inch. Note well: this does not include pads!

Comment: 10mm square body, so about 0.4" square.

Answer (score 5):

\$ \frac {12,20}{11,80} \$ are the maximum and minimum limits of the chip horizontal dimension to the points referenced by the dimension arrows.

**7,50 TYP.** is 7.5 mm TYPical from pin 1 to pin 16 centres.

Comment: European convention uses the comma as the decimal delimiter.  I.e. 12,20 (EU) = 12.20 (US.)

Comment: Good point. I'm an Irish European so I'm used to seeing it although we use '.' for decimals here as in UK.